# Set GITLAB to be accessible on LAN

Tags: networking, gitlab, virtual-machine

After many research i have not found anything...

I install GITLAB on a CentOS VM. The CentOS ip address is 192.168.100.1.
In the file /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb, I modified the line:

```
external_url 'http:192.168.100.1:1234'
```

I executed the command 'gitlab-ctl reconfigure'  and no errors appeared.
When I use Firefox, and I can access to my Gitlab with all the Centos' interfaces:

- 192.168.100.1:1234
- 127.0.0.1:1234

It is normal because when i execute 'netstat -ntlp', I can see:

```
tcp  0  0.0.0.0:1234    LISTEN    22222/nginx:master
```

#### What is the problem?

I cannot access to GitLAB outside from the same Network 192.168.100.1/24.

From an other VM on the same network (192.168.100.2), i can ping '192.168.100.2'. I also make an ssh connection but if I made a:

```
curl 192.168.100.1:1234
```

The result is "Time out"

Thank,

Vincent

Comment: CentOS by default runs a firewall, you might need to check it out and open up for port 1234. (Perhaps disable it temporarily for testing=

Comment: Yes... It was that.... I am ashamed.
I am not used to work on CentOS and I was persuaded that firewall  was off.

Thank.